# Минимальное количество операций из 0 в N

Tags: python, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

Здраствуйте, я только начал свой путь в олимпиадном программировании.
Нужно из `0` получить `N` добавляя два или три. Какое минимальное количество операций потребуется?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: смотрите остаток от деления на 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если непременно нужно решать с помощью ДП (см. комментарий от
splash58), то нетрудно записать рекурсивную функцию

```
F(0,N) = min(F(2,N), F(3,N))
```

На её основе можно сделать мемоизацию - ДП с запоминанием промежуточных результатов.

Но здесь лучше создать массив длиной N+1 и заполнять его снизу, для каждого элемента проверяя -

```
DP[i] = 1 + min(DP[i-2], DP[i-3])
```

`DP[N]` будет содержать количество шагов.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!